# Swift Codable JSON parse error with JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I am trying to handle a JSON with Codable but there's a parsing error when I decode it with JSONDecoder().decode.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "90",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "nameid": "bitcoin",
            "rank": 1,
            "price_usd": "50513.75",
            "percent_change_24h": "3.03",
            "percent_change_1h": "-0.50",
            "percent_change_7d": "-9.91",
            "price_btc": "1.00",
            "market_cap_usd": "942710364520.73",
            "volume24": 70745042591.75044,
            "volume24a": 107034995571.4168,
            "csupply": "18662452.00",
            "tsupply": "18662452",
            "msupply": "21000000"
        },
        {
            "id": "80",
            "symbol": "ETH",
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "nameid": "ethereum",
            "rank": 2,
            "price_usd": "4052.44",
            "percent_change_24h": "10.17",
            "percent_change_1h": "-0.78",
            "percent_change_7d": "17.75",
            "price_btc": "0.084812",
            "market_cap_usd": "466734637594.73",
            "volume24": 53134000887.50444,
            "volume24a": 87082811090.79503,
            "csupply": "115173595.00",
            "tsupply": "115173595",
            "msupply": ""
        }
    ],
    "info": {
        "coins_num": 5949,
        "time": 1621022046
    }
}
```

The json is like above and I coded all my models like below.

```
class CoinModel: Codable {
    var data: [Coin]?
    var info: CoinInfo?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case info
    }
}

class CoinInfo: Codable {
    var coinsNum: Int?
    var time: TimeInterval?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coinsNum = "coins_num"
        case time = "time"
    }
}
```

```
class Coin: Codable{
    var csupply: String?
    var id: String?
    var marketCapUsd: String?
    var msupply: Int?
    var name: String?
    var nameid: String?
    var percentChange1h: String?
    var percentChange24h: String?
    var percentChange7d: String?
    var priceBtc: String?
    var priceUsd: String?
    var rank: Int?
    var symbol: String?
    var tsupply: Int?
    var volume24: Double?
    var volume24a: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case csupply = "csupply"
        case id = "id"
        case marketCapUsd = "market_cap_usd"
        case msupply = "msupply"
        case name = "name"
        case nameid = "nameid"
        case percentChange1h = "percent_change_1h"
        case percentChange24h = "percent_change_24h"
        case percentChange7d = "percent_change_7d"
        case priceBtc = "price_btc"
        case priceUsd = "price_usd"
        case rank = "rank"
        case symbol = "symbol"
        case tsupply = "tsupply"
        case volume24 = "volume24"
        case volume24a = "volume24a"
    }
}
```

And my network function work like below.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        completion(.failure(error!))
        return
    }
    
    guard let data = data else {
        completion(.failure(error ?? NSError()))
        return
    }
    
    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
    
    guard let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CoinModel.self, from: data) else {
        completion(.success([]))
        return
    }
    
    completion(.success(model.data ?? []))
    
}.resume()
```

As I said before, json object is not nil and I got like below.

```
[({
    csupply = "435032301.00";
    id = 33285;
    "market_cap_usd" = "435337535.24";
    msupply = "";
    name = "USD Coin";
    nameid = "usd-coin";
    "percent_change_1h" = "0.01";
    "percent_change_24h" = "0.19";
    "percent_change_7d" = "0.16";
    "price_btc" = "0.000023";
    "price_usd" = "1.00";
    rank = 100;
    symbol = USDC;
    tsupply = 435032301;
    volume24 = "11520659193.03477";
    volume24a = "13684311331.83874";
}
)
, "info": {
    "coins_num" = 5952;
    time = 1621160044;
}]
```

I can handle the JSON with JSONSerialization but I could not find any reason for parse error in the `JSONDecoder` way. I think I did not see the problem. Thanks for any advice and helps.

Edit:

I solved it with several changes in my Codable class, I made a mistake when I describing model for `id`, `csupply` and etc.

```
var csupply: String?
var msupply: String?
var tsupply: String?
```

Comment: Don't use `try ?` - this throws away the error that will probably help you. Use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` in the `catch` block.

Comment: hey @Paulw11 I forgot to use catch error block, I am using right now, I will update the question

Comment: `volume24` and `volume24a` are not `String`s

Comment: I've used a free crypto api and `volume24` & `volume24a` gets like this          "volume24": 70745042591.75044
 "volume24a": 107034995571.4168 . I see them like non-string because of `quote mark` but I am converting it.

Comment: I tried with `Double` but error is same

Comment: What error? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Unrelated but declaring everything schematically as optional is bad practice. The API sends clearly all fields in `Coin`. And - as already mentioned - `catch` always Decoding errors. They are very descriptive and tell you immediately what’s wrong.

Comment: hey, @vadian this is a simple free coin API, so I mean they could remove some parameters from API and it affects the model if I describe the model without optional.

Comment: There is also a native way to convert snake_case to camelCase when decoding, no need to define your coding keys. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase

Comment: If they change the API you won’t even notice it. With non-optional values you get an error (of course if you don’t ignore it).

Comment: @Pancho I tried it remove my coding keys thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes on defining object. For example you have defined `id`, `msupply` is a integer but they are string. You have defined the `volume24` and `volume24a` is string but they are not. You need to fix all of these probably thats why you can't parse it.

All wrong defined parameters are `id`, `mSupply`, `volume24`, `volume24a`, `tSupply` for coin object and for the `info` object you need to convert `time` to `Int` aswell.

Comment: Hey @Alihan, thanks for answer, I changed my model with id as an `String` and volumes as `Double` but I got the error for not correct format.

Comment: Hello @eemrah I've updated my question with full list of wrong defined parameters can you fix all of them and try again?

Comment: hey @Alihan, thanks for answering, I will correct your answer, actually after your first answer I figured out I totally wrong with `csupply` and other supply variables. I made a mistake on their definition and already changed it.